# How to convert online font link into local ones?

Tags: html, css, fonts

How to convert a online font link into local ones? (Probably download the font file is ok)

for example, HTML and CSS from google fonts:

```
HTML:
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

CSS:
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
```

or with import style:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Source+Sans+Pro');
</style>
```

The main goal here is:

After download, and convert to local. The whole website can be served locally in local network, without internet connection.

Comment: You just have to use font-face https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: if you want to work locally you need to download the fonts and install them locally.. thats the only way

Comment: Just download the files on your local system. And remove the Imports. It will work just like a normal font.

Comment: Do check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take help from the [google web font](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) helper. Its really a handy tool to **download the google fonts** and **install them locally**.

> The benefit of this tools and Implementation:

**1. It will provide all format of fonts ( .eot, .woff, .woff2, .svg, .ttf ).**

**2. Help you in implementation with css.** It generates css of the selected font and styles.

```
   example of css code:
/* open-sans-regular - latin */ 
 @font-face {
      font-family: 'Open Sans';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url('../fonts/open-sans-v13-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'),
           url('../fonts/open-sans-v13-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
           url('../fonts/open-sans-v13-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/open-sans-v13-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/open-sans-v13-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('../fonts/open-sans-v13-latin-regular.svg#OpenSans') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

**3. Manually Select all font weights and style you want to include in your project and download them.**
[image]

Comment: This is great! However, is there any more general tools that downloads right from the url (https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto|Source+Sans+Pro) and put in some folders?

Comment: I can write the font-face myself, so if there's some tool to automize the process of downloading, and it'd be great.

Comment: actually there is not any direct way available.. There are other few ways but those are lengthy. so nothing available to download directly from the url at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the font file and declare it in the css :

```css
@font-face { font-family: Roboto; src: url('Roboto.otf'); }
```